# What is Routee in Twilio?

Tags: twilio, twilio-api

When Twilio sends an SMS to a non-domestic number it shows up as Routee and you can not reply to that conversation. However, you can reply directly if you specify the number. This means that to reply to a conversation the user must form the number himself and reply (which isn't a pleasant user experience). Is this a carrier related problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the FAQ entry titled "[Why do some SMS recipients see a Sender ID that is not my Twilio number?](https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/223181088-Why-do-some-SMS-recipients-see-a-Sender-ID-that-is-not-my-Twilio-number-)".

From the article:

*"Sender ID change may occur when you send messages from a Twilio number that is not local to your recipients, for example using a US Twilio number to send SMS to Polish mobile users. This is often done to comply with local regulations, or to ensure the highest possible delivery rate for your messages."*